# JsonField in Django for MySQL

Tags: django, django-mysql

I currently use django 3.2 and MySQL as database, I want use [MySql Json Field](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html). For this reason use [django-mysql](https://pypi.org/project/django-mysql/) third party package in my project.
After create model got this Warning: `(django_mysql.W004) django_mysql.models.JSONField is deprecated. HINT: Use django.db.models.JSONField or django-jsonfield-backport instead.`
If i use  `django.db.models.JSONField` as json field, django use specific MySQL's JsonField ? Dose any effect on preformance? Which one has best performance on database?

Comment: According to the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield), Django 3.1+ supports JSONField for MySQL 5.7.8+.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/releases/3.1/#jsonfield-for-all-supported-database-backends), does not mention a difference in performance. So, probably there is none. It looks like the change is only for supporting all databases with the same unique model field. There is a similar issue in [this link](https://www.untangled.dev/2020/08/07/non-django-issues-in-django-upgrade/). So, you can check that, too. As I read, `django-jsonfield-backport` is for early versions of Django. So, choose according to your version.